# How to Handle onClick and onTouch event on same Button in android

Tags: android

This is my all xml files..........

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/imageButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**imagenext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Image Captured"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"    
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**next.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"    
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Activity ................

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.infobulls.touchdemo;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{

    ImageButton imageButton;
    protected int _splashTime = 3000;

    public boolean isVideoCaptured = false;
    public boolean isImageCaptured = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        isImageCaptured = true;
        isVideoCaptured = true;

        int action = event.getAction();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {   
            try 
            {   
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {                           
                         show();
                    }
                }, _splashTime);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e + "splash screen carsh");
            }


        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            isVideoCaptured = false;
            show();
            if(isImageCaptured)
            {

                Intent image =new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageNextClass.class);
                startActivity(image);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside Up Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        if(isVideoCaptured)
        {
            isImageCaptured=false;
            System.out.println("inside show method=============");
            Intent next =new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextClass.class);
            startActivity(next);                
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageNextClass.java**

```
package com.infobulls.touchdemo;


public class ImageNextClass extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagenext);
    }

}
```

**NextClass.java**

```
package com.infobulls.touchdemo;


public class NextClass extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
    }

}
```

Hello Friends,
              I am trying to run this code but its not properly working because i just want to run above on touch event on same button. but i could not be able to run this code.
here i am not using onClickListener i am only using onTouchListener and perform click and touch both operation on onTouchListener and managing using boolean variable if you are touch on button and hold on.. than after 3 seconds next.java activity called if you are touch and release immediate on button than touch event work like as a click event and imagenext.java activity called.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

try using onClickListener  and setOnLongClickListener

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

   Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "normal Press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

});
```

and than

```
imageButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Long preess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: hi Dhwanik ji, you are right but how to maintain on click and on touch listener on same button when capture image and video in android and image capture immediate and when video capture than video capturing start on after 3 seconds and progressbar also started when video stop than progressbar also stop that's why i'm using onTouchListener